# Why calling an Azure ML classification model via a webservice API not returning probability scores?

Tags: python, azure

I am new to Azure and also a very low-code budding data scientist (which doesn't seem to be going in my favour). Anyways! I trained a model a couple of days ago with Azure AutoML in ML Studio and registered the most succesful model as a webservice with endpoints. Now, when I call this model using the following Python code, it returns predictions only and not probability scores. AutoML has deployed 'Stackensemble' as the best model for the classification problem. I have a lot of code written in Python and would prefer an approach that fits easily within my code rather than something very different. Note: HTTPs and get/post requests are not my strong point so any explanations that are simple to understand will be highly beneficial for me. Thanks!

**Code I use to call api**

`resp = requests.post(scoring_uri, input_testdata_with_2obs, headers=headers)
print (resp.text)`

**What I get (predictions alone):**

"{\"result\": [\"Loss\", \"Loss\"]}"

I have also found the following code online on other posts and in Azure documentation but I do not know how to use it with **already deployed models (post-training)**. Where is the following peice of code need to go in my python code I am using to call the API?

`best_run, fitted_model = automl_run.get_output()
class_prob = fitted_model.predict_proba(X_test)`

Answer (score 0):

This link should help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/data-science-virtual-machine/how-to-track-experiments

```
from azureml.core import Webservice
import json

# if you called your service differently then change the name below
service = Webservice(ws, name="diabetes-service")

input_payload = json.dumps({
    'data': X_test[0:2].tolist(),
    'method': 'predict'  # If you have a classification model, you can get probabilities by changing this to 'predict_proba'.
})

output = service.run(input_payload)

print(output)
```

Step 3 shows how adding 'method' : 'predict_proba' to the JSON file below 'data' allows for predict_proba via the API